# Scanning a pdf file

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

I want to scan a research paper of pdf format  using linux shell command. If I want to print/display only the name of the authors and the title of the paper, is there any specific way to do that?

Comment: There are several ways to extract text from PDFs, you can edit the result to retain only title/names (paper formats are just too varied for meaningful automatization). If it really isn't a PDF, but an image shipped as PDF, some OCR software *might* recover readable text. But for a one-shot job, it is faster to just type it in.

Comment: suppose I have converted to text from. Now how I will find out which is the title and which is the authors name? @vonbrand

Comment: With some PDFs you can get lucky because they provide Title & Author fields, so you can do (for example) `strings "$fname" | grep -Ei '/(Title|Author)'`. It's not guaranteed to work, but it's worth a try. But if you're working with text produced by OCR processing of images, that's unlikely to work.

Comment: I've done something like `pdftotext paper.pdf - | grep -A 10 -B 10 'author'` before. That seemed to be enough to get what I wanted (email addresses) ... really messy though.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in the `pdfinfo` utility which is in the `poppler-utils`
package, on debian and fedora at least. From the help:

> Pdfinfo prints the contents of the 'Info' dictionary (plus  some  other
>   useful information) from a Portable Document Format (PDF) file.
>   The 'Info' dictionary contains the following values:
>
> title
>      subject
>      keywords
>      author
>      creator
>      producer
>      creation date
>      modification date

---

Here is an example output for a document on AIX commands:

```
$ pdfinfo aixcmds2.pdf
Title:          AIX Version 6.1 Commands Reference, Volume 2
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         IBM
Creator:        XPP
Producer:       Acrobat Distiller 7.0 (Windows)
CreationDate:   Mon Jul  9 15:38:26 2007
ModDate:        Mon Jul  9 15:38:26 2007
Tagged:         yes
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          746
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot:       0
File size:      8588481 bytes
Optimized:      yes
PDF version:    1.3
```

If you only want the author ('IBM' in this example) you can do, for example,

```
pdfinfo aixcmds2.pdf | sed -n 's/^Author: *//p'
```

or if you want title and author, with the headings:

```
$ pdfinfo aixcmds2.pdf | sed -n '/^\(Author\|Title\):/p'
Title:          AIX Version 6.1 Commands Reference, Volume 2
Author:         IBM
```

Comment: is there any way to use these title, subject, keywords ,author, creator ,producer ,creation date ,modification date info individually. I mean if I want to display only the author then what I will have to do? @meuh

Comment: I added some examples.